# Delete Field from Document from Firestore

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-layout

I'm trying to delete a field from a Document in Firestore with flutter. I could manage to delete the Document, But I can't seem to delete the field inside this document.
This is how I manage to delete the document:

```
Firestore.instance.collection('dadosusuarios').document(user.uid)
                                  .collection('buttons').document('button3').delete();
```

But how could I do this to a field instead of a Document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use  `FiledValue.delete()`

```
Firestore.instance.collection('dadosusuarios').document(user.uid).collection('buttons').document('button3').updateData({
"data":FieldValue.delete(),
});
```